# CodeIgniter index.php 404

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I am using CodeIgniter for both frontend and backend. My backend isn't really that complex so it didn't warrant a different installation of CI. What I have now is a sub directory in controllers `cms` where I have all my backend controllers including a backend `Index` which extends `MY_Backend` core. Now I'm working on getting my front end up and running and have come across a problem if I have an `Index` file in the main controllers directory that extends `MY_Frontend` core. And try to access it via localhost or localhost/index I get a 404 page. If I change the name and subsequently the class name to `Homepage` I can access it via localhost/homepage.

Is this possibly due to having an Index file in the cms sub-directory? Otherwise, what is the issue? Here is my directory structure:

[image]

Comment: I would not name a controller index rename it to something else like Home because there is all ready a index.php in the main directory

Comment: yea I understand, but is that what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

As at the base of it all controllers extend CI_Controller, there are 3 naming restrictions in place for controllers:

- CI_Controller
- Index
- Default

Using any of these would cause a problem in some shape or form. I'd suspect this would be why your controller works fine named as Homepage, but not as Index.

*Source: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html*